# xampp problem trying to dowload a file outside documentRoot

Tags: php, xampp, vhosts

I have this in vhost :

```
<VirtualHost url.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "e:\xampp\htdocs\project"
    ServerName url.com
    <Directory "e:\xampp\htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I'm trying to download a file from  htdocs\downloads...

in php code when I do this:

```
    file_exists('../../downloads/fcm/'.$fcmb.'.pdf')
```

the result is 1  but when i do this

```
<a href="../../downloads/fcm/<? echo $fcmb;?>.pdf" target="_blank"><? echo $fcmb;?></a>
```

the result is ERROR 404

thing is I don't know how to download a file outside the project directory I tried different ways but not working

Comment: You can NOT redirect users to folders outside DocumentRoot!
You can Serve files from other folders, but user MUST access this files via DocumentRoot folder or its subfolders. So Direct a href link will not work. Use PHP to serve this file instead.

Comment: so if I force the download with php it should work?

Comment: PHP can access folders outside DocumentRoot. A web browser can not, as URLs are limited to the DocumentRoot folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your download page should be something like:

```
$file = '../../downloads/fcm/'.$fcmb.'.pdf';

if (is_file($file)) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $file));
    finfo_close($finfo);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```